# How to associate file extensions with program using wildcard in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have log files that are named so

`Service.log20150620`
`Service.log20150621`
`Service.log20150622`

How can I associate all of them with a program in Windows 7 without doing it individually for each extension?

Comment: It would be easier if you named your logfiles `Service.[date].log`. `.log` files are already associated with `notepad` (by default)

Comment: I know it would be easier, but that's how log4net does it by default. Also I have lot of older log files I want to open with a double click in this convention

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't.

The file associations are stored individually under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` in the registry.  Even similar extensions are stored separately: .jpeg .jpg, .htm .html.

Consider adjusting the filename output format to `Service.<date>.log`.  If this is not possible to configure, write a script which periodically renames the files appropriately.

**EDIT (you mentioned log4net):** According to the following StackOverflow post, you should be able to modify the logfile format to put the date earlier in the filename.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615092/log4net-rolling-file-appender-define-extension/615137#615137